# Mathjax + Markdown + Jekyll, Mobile Device White Object Covering Math Text Issue

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages, mathjax, mobile-website

I want to write some inline math using mathjax + markdown with jekyll. However I am getting the following issue on some of the math text. In this case, some white object appears on mobile devices, blocking out the top half of some of the mathjax text. However once I zoom my screen in on my mobile device, the white blocking object disappears. What could be the issue here?

```
$$n$$
```

[image: issue]

Comment: Try adding a self-contained example exhibiting the problem (or at least a link to the page) and write more about how to reproduce the issue (OS and browser version, which kind of zoom feature etc).

Comment: And a random guess would be that it's this known bug https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2435

Comment: Oh thanks, I will follow that thread. Thanks!